# How to limit amount of pages in laravel pagination?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, pagination, laravel-pagination

I have a pagination and try to limit the amount of pages for that pagination. Every page has 50 results and the maximum amount of pages I want for this pagination is 200 (10k total entries from the table). I tried the following:

```
$page_count = 50;
$users = DB::Table('user_totalpoints')->where('points', '>', 0)
        ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
        ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
        ->take(10000)
        ->paginate($page_count);
```

The result of this is a pagination with 50 results per page but with ALL entries from the user_totalpoints table. take(10000) is ignored as there are only 50 taken by the pagination. So instead of maximum 200pages I now have thousands.

How can I limit the amount of pages for my pagination in laravel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manual Paginator [LengthAwarePaginator](https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html)

```php
// limit page max to 200 and min to 1
$this->validate($request, [
    'page' => 'required|integer|min:1|max:200'
]);
$page = $request->get('page');
$page_count = 50;
$total = 10000;

$users = DB::Table('user_totalpoints')->where('points', '>', 0)
    ->orderBy('points', 'desc')
    ->orderBy('id', 'asc')
    ->forPage($page, $page_count)
    ->get();
/**
 * use Illuminate\Pagination\LengthAwarePaginator;
 */
$paginator = new LengthAwarePaginator($users, $total, $page_count, $page);
dd($paginator->toArray()); // view result
```

Comment: With `$total` in the `LengthAwarePaginator ` like this it'll always show 10000, even if there's fewer results. So remove `->forPage($page, $page_count)`, and instead of `$total` add `$users->count() > $total ? $total : $users->count()`.